# Android in-app logging

Tags: android, logging

I'm making a library that can be used to log errors and other events in Android apps, before being sent to a server via HTTPS PUT. Is this possible using the native [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class 
or is there a better way to do this? Support for batch-uploading the logs would be a bonus, but I am happy to implement that myself if necessary.

Essentially what I'm looking for is a logger that can be configured to send logs to a server rather than saving them locally, and that can perform this in the background without significantly affecting the performance of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own logger class. Say you call the class "`MyLogger`", you can then create some methods that mimick the android methods, like `MyLogger.logI(name,text);` etc.

Within your `logI` method you can print to the standard android logs as usual (`Log.i(...);`) and you can also send the text in the log to your http server.

If you need help with the http request, you should look at the `apache commons` documentation for a good implementation. All you need to do is create the http request, add the data to the `HttpPut` instance, and then send the request to the server (dealing with it in however way you see fit on the server). Make sure you do it in an `AsyncTask`, otherwise you may slow down the ui etc if you are not using a background thread.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - now I know where to start. I had already looked into the uploading of logs using `HttpClient`, but using a `Service`, specifically an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). Would an AsyncTask be better, or would that only be necessary if the uploading process needs to interact with the UI after completion?

Comment: The danger with a service is it is more of a standalone entity in your application - it has it's own context etc. You would be better off going for an AsyncTask, as once it is completed that will be it, and you can of course run it again next time it is needed

Comment: That makes sense, particularly since uploading may be done frequently. Thanks!